# Менеджер закачек

Tags: c#, download

пытался написать консольное приложение для скачивания файлов по ссылкам с таймером(ссылки лежат в txt файле, представляют собой прямые ссылки на скачивание с google sheets), программа работает в фоне и каждые n-минут скачивает необходимые файлы и если они лежат уже в дирректории, то они перезаписываются.
Проблема в следующем, есть ссылка формата https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AeZH8xc6kqheVKCKLqW70azeY7sX0DM5Lp_o0oQJ9xI/export?format=xlsx
и прога мало того что не скачивает, она сохраняет export?format=xlsx в виде пустого файла. Я уже не знаю куда копать и опустил руки. Если необходимо, могу предоставить сырцы.
Теперь вопрос, есть ли готовые решения того что я описал выше? то есть вбиваешь необходимые ссылки в интерфейсе или конфиг файле и раз в определенное время программа скачивает их снова и снова и перезаписывает их если необходимо?
Советовали wget, но я с ним ни разу не работал(

Answer (score 2):

Простейший код

```
var link = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AeZH8xc6kqheVKCKLqW70azeY7sX0DM5Lp_o0oQJ9xI/export?format=xlsx";
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(link);
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\temp\_test\out.xlsx", bytes);       
}
```

Отрабатывает как надо и сохраняет файл на диске

[image: ...]

Answer (score 0):

Даже если послать запрос вообще без всего, файл отлично отдаётся. Так что у тебя явно косяк где-то в другом месте.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Не, дело в том, что если я даю ссылку формата www.рогаикопыта.чтототам/файл.расширение то он качает нормально.
Но вот если качать прямые гугловские ссылки, то тут уже не работает

Comment: Значит ты что-то делаешь не так.

Comment: знаю, тогда буду копать сырцы